# PhpStorm Symfony routes missing

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

I have a rather large Symfony 4.4 project that I recently reopened.  Going through the code with PhpStorm 2020.3, adding some new functionality and code cleanup.

I get to a couple of Controllers and I'm getting a "Missing Route" error in PhpStorm.  However, the routes do exist when I run `php bin/console debug:router`.

Is there a cache that I haven't cleared to cause PhpStorm to rescan routes?

**Output from: `php bin/console debug:router`**

> admin_deviceprofile_index                    GET        ANY      ANY    /admin/deviceprofile/
> admin_deviceprofile_show                     GET        ANY      ANY    /admin/deviceprofile/{deviceprofile_id}/show
> admin_deviceprofile_create                   GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /admin/deviceprofile/create
> admin_deviceprofile_edit                     GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /admin/deviceprofile/{deviceprofile_id}/edit
> admin_deviceprofile_delete                   DELETE     ANY      ANY    /admin/deviceprofile/{deviceprofile_id}/delete

My snippet of the Controller ...

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/deviceprofile",
 *     name="admin_deviceprofile_")
 */
class DeviceProfileController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * Lists all Device Profiles.
     * @Route("/",
     *     name="index",
     *     methods={"GET"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    { ... }

    /**
     * Creates a new Device Profile entity.
     * @Route("/create",
     *     name="create",
     *     methods={"GET", "POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create(Request $request): Response
    {
        $profile = new DeviceProfile();
        $formProfile = $this->createForm(DeviceProfileType::class, $profile);
        $formProfile->handleRequest($request);

        if ($formProfile->isSubmitted() && $formProfile->isValid()) {
            ...
            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_deviceprofile_index');
        }

        return $this->render(...);
    }
}
```

PhpStorm claims the `'admin_deviceprofile_index'` is Missing.  However, it is not.  Also, this same pattern of having a route for the controller is used elsewhere, yet those routes are fine, the problem appears in just a couple of Controllers.

Also, through debugging this 'problem', I moved the controller route partials to the functions themselves, and PhpStorm still did not see the routes properly.

I have also ran `php bin/console cache:clear` and have done the PhpStorm: **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart** to no avail.

Anything I could try to clear this up?  I loathe seeing "errors" in the code inspection.

Comment: Such Symfony specific functionality is provided by the [Symfony Support plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219-symfony-support). Maybe check their [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues). P.S. I'm not a Symfony user so not sure what exactly is required .. but since that path is declared via `@Route` -- do you have PHP Annotations plugin installed? It is the one that handles such annotations (maybe it's needed here as well).

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that if you have a PhpStorm @noinspection tag block and a class-level docblock, it will conflict causing the erroneous "Missing Route" message.

[Github issue here](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/1573)